# how to get "connectionStateUpdatedTime" from IOT HUB using node js sdk 'azure-iothub'

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-hub-device-management

I am using "('azure-iothub').Registry" to get device twin data.

```
strQuery = `SELECT * FROM devices where deviceId IN [${deviceIds}]`;
query = registry.createQuery(strQuery, 500);
```

but device twin does not have "connectionStateUpdatedTime" property.
As per MS document, it is in device identity.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-identity-registry#device-identity-properties

**is there a way to get "connectionStateUpdatedTime" property?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not get `connectionStateUpdatedTime` using [above approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-query-language#nodejs-example), as it returns below schema:

```
{
    "deviceId": "myDeviceId",
    "etag": "AAAAAAAAAAc=",
    "status": "enabled",
    "statusUpdateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "connectionState": "Disconnected",
    "lastActivityTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "cloudToDeviceMessageCount": 0,
    "authenticationType": "sas",
    "x509Thumbprint": {
        "primaryThumbprint": null,
        "secondaryThumbprint": null
    },
    "version": 2,
    "tags": {
        "location": {
            "region": "US",
            "plant": "Redmond43"
        }
    },
    "properties": {
        "desired": {
            "telemetryConfig": {
                "configId": "db00ebf5-eeeb-42be-86a1-458cccb69e57",
                "sendFrequencyInSecs": 300
            },
            "$metadata": {
            ...
            },
            "$version": 4
        },
        "reported": {
            "connectivity": {
                "type": "cellular"
            },
            "telemetryConfig": {
                "configId": "db00ebf5-eeeb-42be-86a1-458cccb69e57",
                "sendFrequencyInSecs": 300,
                "status": "Success"
            },
            "$metadata": {
            ...
            },
            "$version": 7
        }
    }
}
```

You are referring to identity registry which is a REST-capable collection of device or module identity resources. When you add an entry in the identity registry, IoT Hub creates a set of per-device resources such as the queue that contains in-flight cloud-to-device messages. For more information about the import and export APIs, see [IoT Hub resource provider REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/iothubresource).

*For your requirement, you can use [Devices - Get Devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/devices/get-devices) API*:

```
GET https://fully-qualified-iothubname.azure-devices.net/devices?api-version=2020-05-31-preview
```

*which will give you response as [Device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/devices/get-devices#device) array which will have `connectionStateUpdatedTime`.*

Let me know if you have follow up questions or if I understood your question incorrectly.